# Mobile auth verifyPhoneNumber logs in user

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

The verifyPhoneNumber method is logging in the already existing user.
When the user is using an already existing mobile number, it just logs him to the app, instead of throwing an exception.

This is because I'm using the `signInWithCredential` method.

So how can I show the user that this mobile number is already registered?

It doesn't seem right to not have a registration method different from the sign in method.

```
Future<void> _verifyMobileNumber2({
  @required BuildContext context,
  @required String mobileNumber,
  @required String landlineNumber,
  @required String licenseNumber,
  @required String name,
  @required String email,
}) {
  String formattedMobileNumber = _formatMobileNumber(mobileNumber);  // to the format used by firebase

  return FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: formattedMobileNumber,
    verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) async {

      final UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      await userCredential.user.updateEmail(email);

      await userCredential.user.updateProfile(displayName: name);

      await userCredential.user.reload();

    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication doesn't make a distinction between signing **up** with a phone number and signing **in* with a phone number. When somebody has access to a phone number, they can sign into Firebase with it.

This is one of the reasons its documentation calls out this [security concern](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#security-concerns):

> Authentication using only a phone number, while convenient, is less secure than the other available methods, because possession of a phone number can be easily transferred between users. Also, on devices with multiple user profiles, any user that can receive SMS messages can sign in to an account using the device's phone number.

> If you use phone number based sign-in in your app, you should offer it alongside more secure sign-in methods, and inform users of the security tradeoffs of using phone number sign-in.

This also explains how to better secure a use-case that allows signing in with a phone number: you'll want to add an additional sign-in mechanism.

If this doesn't suit your needs, you'll have to find another auth provider that implements the phone auth flow you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Frank. This was really helpful. I have read that section in the documentation before, but I only actually understood it now.